# Как работают вызовы метода при наследовании? C#

Tags: c#, наследование

Начал изучать C#. И возник вопрос с созданием классов и наследованием.
У нас есть два класса Class1 и Class2. Class2 является наследником Class1.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 c = new Class2();
            c.f();
        }

        class Class1
        {
            public void f()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Я класс 1\n");
            }
        }

        class Class2 : Class1
        {
            public new void f()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Я класс 2\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При выполнении этого кода в консоли выводится "Я класс 1". Почему так происходит, если я создаю экземпляр класса Class2? Лично я думал, что должен выполнятся переопределённый метод.

Comment: [new modifier (C# Reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)

Comment: для переопределения метода, базоый метод должен быть виртуальным, а новый с ключевым словом override. То, что вы делаете, называется сокрытие метода, оно работает немного по другому.

Comment: Если вы не делаете override - то зависит от контекста вызова, даже если создаёте унаследованный экземпляр. Создав экземпляр Class2, но записав ссылку на него в переменные типа Class1 или Class2 - будут производиться вызовы соответствующих методов, а не унаследованного.

Comment: Да, удалось разобраться. Большое всем спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Либо так надо:

```cs
((Class2)c).f();
```

Либо так:

```cs
class Class1
{
    public virtual void f()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Я класс 1");
    }
}

class Class2 : Class1
{
    public override void f()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Я класс 2");
    }
}
```

Полиморфизм реализуется через ключевые слова `virtual-override`.